# How many partitions $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are there of a set $S$, $|S| = 30$, and $|A_i| = 10$?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, set-partition, multinomial-coefficients

Let $S$ be a set with $|S| = 30$ and let $\pi = \{A_i\}_{i=1}^3$ be a partition of $S$ such that each set $A_i$ of $\pi$ has ten elements. How many such partitions $\pi$ are there?

This questions seems like a deceptively easy question, i.e., just a combination problem. Pick ${30\choose 10}$ for $A_1$, ${30-10\choose 10}$ for $A_2$, and ${30-20\choose 10}$ for $A_3$ Then we have ${30\choose 10}{20\choose 10}{10\choose 10}$. But we don't care in what order the 3 partitions are so finally answer is
$$\frac{{30\choose 10}{20\choose 10}{10\choose 10}}  {3!}.$$
Is this a sufficient answer?

Comment: Yeah, it is ok.

Comment: From the tag description for [tag:solution-verification]: *"This should not be the only tag for a question."*

Comment: @Shaun, I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you, @Owen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  You can also write this in terms of a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients):
$$\frac{\binom{30}{10,10,10}}{3!} = \frac{30!/10!^3}{3!}$$